# Mysql Substr index and multiple group by conditions

Tags: mysql, group-by, conditional-statements

I'm trying to get the totals of a table grouped by names that are similar. Here is my test mysql:

```
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS aa (
     clicks INT NOT NULL, 
     locn varchar (30) NOT NULL
    ) CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci;
          
    insert into aa values(1, 'page?1'),   
                         (1, 'page?2'),
                         (1, 'page?3'),
                         (1, 'item(12)'),                     
                         (1, 'item(22)'),                     
                         (1, 'item(32)');
```

If I run this command

```
    SELECT count(clicks), substring_index(locn, '(',1) as a FROM aa group by a;
```

the result is

```
    3 item
    1 page?1
    1 page?2
    1 page?3
```

If I run

```
    SELECT count(clicks), substring_index(locn, '?',1) as b FROM aa group by b ;
```

the result is

```
    1 item(12)
    1 item(22)
    1 item(32)
    3 page
```

So each of those work but I can't figure out how to get them to work together. Would someone explain how to do this, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT count(clicks), substring_index(substring_index(locn, '(', 1), '?', 1) as a 
FROM aa group by a;
```

Result given your data:

```
+---------------+------+
| count(clicks) | a    |
+---------------+------+
|             3 | page |
|             3 | item |
+---------------+------+
```

Comment: Thank you for the fix. It worked exactly as needed. Looking down the road, it is possible to have other conditions checked? So now the two conditions are ( and ?. What if a third is added at some point that is *, or whatever?

Comment: Then you would need a third nested substring_index(). Of course this will become impractical if you have lots of other cases to search for. If that is something you need to handle, then use Akina's solution.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(locn, '\\w+'), COUNT(*)
FROM aa
GROUP BY 1
```

| REGEXP_SUBSTR(locn, '\w+') | COUNT(*) |
| --- | --- |
| page | 3 |
| item | 3 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/NwX-YLhd)

Comment: PS. The solution provided by Bill Karwin must be more fast..

Comment: They will both do a table-scan. The difference between regexp_substr and other methods of string manipulation are minor.

Comment: @BillKarwin I have tested on the randomly generated values similar to shown ones. The time relation is ~ 3:4.